# Divide a group into n and add block numbers for each group in python

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby, grouping

I have the following table:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| B | 32 |
| C | 44 |
| D | 76 |
| E | 99 |
| F | 123 |
| G | 65 |
| H | 87 |
| I | 76 |
| J | 231 |
| k | 80 |
| l | 55 |
| m | 27 |
| n | 67 |

I would like to divide this table in to 'n' (n = 4, here) groups and add another column with group name. The output should look like the following:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 1 |
| B | 32 | 1 |
| C | 44 | 1 |
| D | 76 | 1 |
| E | 99 | 2 |
| F | 123 | 2 |
| G | 65 | 2 |
| H | 87 | 2 |
| I | 76 | 3 |
| J | 231 | 3 |
| k | 80 | 3 |
| l | 55 | 4 |
| m | 27 | 4 |
| n | 67 | 4 |

What I tried so for?

```
TGn = 4
idx = set(df.index // TGn)

treatment_groups = [i for i in range(1, n+1)]
df['columnC'] = (df.index // TGn).map(dict(zip(idx, treatment_groups)))
```

This does not split the group properly, not sure where I went wrong. How do I correct it?

Comment: If the `df ` had 13 rows how would you want `ColumnC`? in groups of 4, 4, 3, and 2? or 4, 4, 4, and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your sample size is exactly divided by n (i.e. `sample_size%n` is 0):

```
import numpy as np
groups = range(1,n+1)

df['columnC'] = np.repeat(groups,int(len(df)/n))
```

If your sample size is not exactly divided by n (i.e. `sample_size%n` is not 0):

```
# Assigning the remaining rows to random groups
df['columnC'] = np.concatenate(
                [np.repeat(groups,int(len(df)/n)), 
                 np.random.randint(1, high=n, size=int(len(df)%n), dtype=int)])

# Assigning the remaining rows to group 'm'
df['columnC'] = np.concatenate(
                [np.repeat(groups,int(len(df)/n)), 
                 np.repeat([m],int(len(df)%n)), dtype=int)])
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. The original table contains 91 rows. When I try to execute this it throws me the following error; "ValueError: Length of values (88) does not match length of index (91)". Since the sample size is not divisible ny n.

Comment: It is your choice as to what would you want to do with the remaining rows. Either you can randomly assign the remaining rows to groups or you assign them to one particular group.